# Android Async Task one after another

Tags: android, parsing, soap, android-asynctask, download

I have an existing code which has an Async Task used for some request-response.
In the post execute method it sets the parsed data into some db.

Now I need to modify this code in such a way that at app launch, the data gets downloaded one by one.
i.e. I need to execute task A, then on  its full completion (even the data is set) I need to start task B and so on for around 12 tasks.

Note: I need to finish the "post execute" as well before starting the next task.

I am not sure how to do this.
Please suggest.

Comment: Theoretically its simple, create a class which extends AsyncTask, create their instance list and execute each one on post execute.

Comment: Can't you create "Task B" inside the onPostExecute of "Task A" and start execute it?

Comment: no. because this task may be called later again, to refresh the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation depends on your requirement.

1. If after every call you need to update your UI you can download and save data in `doInBackground()` and the update in `onPostExecute()`.
2. If you wanna update your UI just once then download all the data inside a loop inside your `doInBackground()` and also save your data in db there only and finally call your `onPostExecute()` just once.
3. If it has nothing to do with updating the UI then you can simply use `Thread`.

**NOTE :** `AsyncTask` **order of execution will be serial only above** `HoneyComb` **below that it would be parallel.**

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with `myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor (SERIAL_EXECUTOR)`

```
AsyncTask a = new AsyncTask();
AsyncTask b = new AsyncTask();
AsyncTask c = new AsyncTask();

a.executeOnExecutor (SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
b.executeOnExecutor (SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
c.executeOnExecutor (SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

Now the exection order will be a -> b -> c;

Comment: actually I am not able to use this properly.

Comment: I tried searching about the proper usage...but no luck.any useful link would be appreciated.

Comment: How to get a callback from all async task is completed or not ?

Answer (score 3):

This one gets a bit messy..

Configuring a AsyncTask with [SERIAL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) will indeed **force serial execution of background logic**,
that is, the logic contained within the doInBackground() calls.

SERIAL_EXECUTOR **makes no guarantees as to when the onPostExecute() will be invoked**.

Executing a set of AsyncTask in SERIAL_EXECUTOR mode may result in onPostExecute() of task A being 
executed **after** the doInBackground() of task B.

If the latter demand is not crucial to your system, just use SERIAL_EXECUTOR and be happy.

But, if it is, you will need to change your architecture in a way that will force
such demand.

one way of doing so will be as follows:

```
class MyAsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected  Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // do background work
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // update UI here
            new MyNextAsyncTask.execute(..); // <---------- start next task only after UI update has completed
        }

}
```

That is: you will **wait for the UI update of one operation to complete before starting the next one.**

Another way, which I would probably prefer, would be to manage th entire task flow
within a single thread that internally perform att background tasks A -> B -> C ....
and, in between, issues UI update commands and waits on a ConditionVariable for these
tasks to complete

```
new Thread()  {

     ConditionVariable mCondition = new ConditionVariable(false);
     void run() {

          do_A();

          runonUIThread(updateAfter_A_Runnable);

          mPreviewDone.block(); // will be release after updateAfterA_Runnable completes!


          do_B();

          runonUIThread(updateAfter_B_Runnable);

          mPreviewDone.block(); // will be release after updateAfter_B_Runnable completes!



          etc..
     }

}
```

Hope it helps.