# Multiple Async Tasks one after another Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to fetch data from server in saving in `SQLite` database through `Async task` on Splash. i have multiple tables on server and need to fetch one after another. I'm trying this way

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
            .penaltyLog().build());

    url = getResources().getString(R.string.url);

    db = new SQLCont(context);

    new asyn_Task1(Splash.this).execute();

}

public class asyn_Task1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    public asyn_Task1(Splash activiy) {
        context = activiy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        new asyn_Task2(Splash.this).execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(Splash.this);
        progressdialog.setTitle("Processing....");
        progressdialog.setMessage("Please Wait.....1 /10");
        progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {


        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("001", data));

        try {

            CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet("001");

        } catch (Exception e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String response = null;

        // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters

        try {

            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(

            url,

            postParameters);

            // store the result returned by PHP script that runs
            // MySQL query

            String result = response.toString();

            // parse json data
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    id = json_data.getString("id");
                    st_name = " " + json_data.getString("name");
                    st_contact = json_data.getString("contact");
                    st_category = json_data.getString("Category");
                    st_address = json_data.getString("address");

                    Log.d("favourite_data", "" + id + st_name + st_contact
                            + st_category + st_address);

                    db.adddata_hospital(context, st_name,st_contact,
                            st_category, st_address);


                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());

        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class asyn_Task2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    public asyn_Task2(Splash activiy) {
        context = activiy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        new asyn_Task3(Splash.this).execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        // some stuff here

        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class asyn_Task3 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    public asyn_blood_Group(Splash activiy) {
        context = activiy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressdialog.dismiss();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

      // some stuff here
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

problem is that data is added for `asyn_Task1` it repeated every time

expected out put

```
  abc  def  ghi 

  jkl  mno  pqr 

  mno  pqr   stu
```

But getting output

```
 abc  def  ghi

 abc  def  ghi

 abc  def  ghi
```

Comment: What is the need of having multiple asynctasks after one another. Why don't you do all things in single asynctask?

Comment: how it can be . i need to get data from different tables in store locally in different tables in sqlite...

Comment: This is because every time onCreate is executed asyn_Task1 is executed.

Comment: You can create "worker tasks" and a queue of items to download. That way you can create a single threadsafe method in the queue class where the asynctasks can get their next task after they are done.

Comment: @user use a Executor

Comment: i have tried this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24604799/android-async-task-one-after-another/24605009#24605009

Comment: @Vibhor how to resolve this .

Comment: @user the one with 2 upvotes should work for you for running background tasks in parallel which is what you need to do.

Comment: i have tried that one but it didn't work for me it executes only 1st and gives gives time out exception after a long time ..

Comment: are you sure you have different http request parameters for every task ?

Comment: yup i have different .. if i do async_Task2 first it will give output repeatedly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get your data based on your query. If you always execute same query then you will always get same data.

And from my point of view if possible single AsyncTask for  that purpose. when all the query is completed then onpostExecute() callback will fired.

Comment: in other case if i use single Async Task.. i have to add data in different tables in sqlite how it can b differentiate..

Comment: You can put the table name is a collection and use a counter which will help to retrieve  next table name from collection after each completed query .  Or you can Create a class  where save Table name and query and other thing. and access them as required.

Comment: thats great .. i got it, v'l try now.. thanx a lot.